# Solve the reccurence relation $a_n = a_{n-2}, a_0=a_1 = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is my first time working through this type of problem and I am looking to see if I have worked it out correctly, thanks!

> Solve the reccurence relation $$a_n = a_{n-2}, a_0=a_1 = 1$$

First we get the characteristic equation:

$$x^n = x^{n-2}$$

Dividing by the smallest we get,

$$x^2=1$$
$$x = \pm 1$$

Using the auxiliary equation: general solution

$$a_n = A_1x^{n+1} + A_2x^{n+1}$$

Using conditions in the equation and our solution for $x$ gives,

$$a_0 = 1 = A_1(1) + A_2(-1) = A_1 - A_2$$
$$a_1 = 1 = A_1(1)^2 = A_2(-1)^2 = A_1 + A_2$$

Solving for $A_1, A_2$ I got $A_1 = 1, A_2 = 0$

Therefore plugging into the general solution I got,

$$a_n = 1^{n+1}$$

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: should the answer just be 1? or should I leave it as I have it

Comment: It should be 1.

Comment: okay I will change that in my answer, thanks!

Comment: Just curious, are you forced to solve this problem by the characteristic equation? Otherwise the answer is trivial...

Comment: its just what I have learned,

Comment: The question is, proving it by what you learned is a useful exercise, but proving it because it is trivial is easier.  So $a_0 = 1$ and $a_n= a_{n-2}$ means $1 = a_0 = a_2= a_4 = .... = a_{2n}$ and $a_1 = 1$ means $1=a_1 = a_3 = a_5 = ..... = a_{2n+1} = a_{n}$ for all $n$.  Trivial.  Even if it *isn't* what you have learned.  ... So the question is... Do you *need* to solve the problem by the caracteristic equation.

Comment: @fleablood thanks, I have made another post, could you confirm this solution? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675316/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-n-digit-ternary-0-1-2-in-which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_{2n}=a_{2n-2}=a_0=1$$

$$a_{2n+1}=a_{2n-1}=a_1=1$$

thus

$$\forall n\in \Bbb N \;a_n=1$$

Comment: okay thanks for confirming my solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use the method of generating functions (overkill but why not). Set $a_n=0$ for $n<0$ and extend  the recurrence relation to
$$
a_n=a_{n-2}+\delta_{n,1}+\delta_{n,0}\quad (n\geq 0)\tag{1}
$$
so that it is valid for all $n\geq 0$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta. Let $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and multiply both sides of (1) by $x^n$ and sum on $n$ to get that
$$
A(x)=x^2A(x)+x+1\iff A(x)(1-x^2)=1+x.
$$
In particular
$$
A(x)=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)(1+x)}=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$
whence
$$
a_n=1\quad (n\geq0).
$$

Answer (score 1):

We transform $a_{n} = a_{n-2}$ to $a_{n+2} = a_n$ and $a_0=a_1=0$.

Using generating functions (with $A(x):=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n} x^n$) this leads to

$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+2} x^n &=& \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n} x^n \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{A(x)}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x} &=& A(x) \\
\Leftrightarrow A(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} &=& \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n
\end{eqnarray*}$

If we look now at the coefficient of $[x^n]$ with see that it is $1$ and therefore $a_n = 1$.